# How to extract compressed polygon contours from a binary mask?

Tags: python, opencv, polygon, shapely

I have a numpy array containing a binary mask `mask`, with shape (N, M). I would like to extract the contours of the mask as a polygon. My current approach is the following:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

mask = ... # boolean numpy array with shape (N, M)
contours, _= cv2.findContours(mask.astype(np.uint8).copy(), 
                              mode=cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                              method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
polygons = []
for cnt in contours:
    sqz_cnt = np.squeeze(cnt, axis=1)
    if len(sqz_cnt) > 3:  # a polygon must contain at least 3 points
        polygon = Polygon(sqz_cnt).exterior.coords
        x_coords = [c[0] for c in polygon]
        y_coords = [c[1] for c in polygon]
        sgm = []
        for x, y in zip(x_coords, y_coords):
            sgm.extend([float(x), float(y)])
            polygons.append(sgm)
```

However, the polygons seem pretty long lists. Is there any way of reducing the length of this polygons? I have tried to simply remove coordinates in `x_coords` and `y_coords`, but then the resulting mask looks completely messed up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cv.approxPolyDP` to simplify the detected contours. [Online example](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/js_contour_features_approxPolyDP.html).

[Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga0012a5fdaea70b8a9970165d98722b4c) for the C++ version of this function; not sure where to find Python docs.